# How to bundle static files into chromium builds?

Tags: chromium

If I wanted to bundle JS/CSS files into chromium builds and not have them requested over network for my web app, how would I go about doing that?

Right now I am able to checkout and build chromium locally and I was just curious if this is possible to do? I heard about some tailwind/nextjs stuff being baked into some future versions of chrome and wanted to see how they would do it?

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do by bundling those files?

Comment: Hoping to serve them from chrome directly instead of having to request from the server